# Submit button doesn't use padding the way input fields do

Tags: html, css, padding

I've been trying to make a form where the elements are all the same width after padding and margin are factored in. The elements I've used successfully are the `<textarea>`, `<input type="text">`, and `<div>` tags. I've been successful for the most part, but the `<input type="submit">` element doesn't seem to use horizontal padding the same way any other element does. Am I missing something?

How can I get them all to be the same width without sacrificing my padding?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4kA8k/

For the sake of thoroughness, I'm using Chrome and have checked that this happens in IE as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following lines in your CSS might do the trick so that all HTML-elements behave (kind of) equal:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: That was exactly it, thank you! I've never stumbled across box-sizing, so I guess I have some reading to do.